# Probability of two dependent events

Tags: probability

I saw a nice problem on probability online but not sure how to tackle it.

In CS:GO, Bob is using Desert Eagle with 7 bullets in one clip. Bob has a .5 chance of landing the bullet. Of the bullets that landed, there is .2 chance that it is a headshot. If it is a headshot, the target dies instantly, otherwise Bob would need 3 (non-consecutive or consecutive) landed bullets to eliminate the target. What is the probability that Bob eliminate a target with one clip?

So I started out naively with something like, $$P(\text{at least 3 landed shots}) = 1 - 0.5^7 - {7 \choose 1}0.5^7 - {7 \choose 2} 0.5^7 = .77$$
and similarly with $$P(\text{at least 1 headshot}) = 1  - 0.9^7 = .52$$
but not sure how to continue. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes as you started, it is easier to first find probability, say $Q$, that Bob is not able to kill the target in one clip ($7$ bullets).

This can only happen if Bob does not land any bullet on the target or lands either one or two bullets but they are not headshot. The probability that a landed bullet is not a headshot is $0.8$.

$Q = \displaystyle 0.5^7 + {7 \choose 1} (0.5)^7 \times 0.8 + {7 \choose 2} (0.5)^7 \times (0.8)^2 \approx 0.1566$

So the probability that Bob kills the target is $P = 1 - Q \approx 0.8434$.

Comment: That is much clearer! But why do we use the P(landed bullet that is a headshot) and not the P(bullet is a headshot)?

Comment: For a bullet to be a headshot, it needs to land at the target. The question gives probability of landing as $0.5$ and it says $0.2$ probability that a _landed bullet_ is a headshot. The probability of a _headshot_ is in fact zero for a bullet that does not land. So we work with max $2$ landings for target to survive and all landings must be other than headshot.

Comment: I was thinking P(bullet is a headshot) = P(bullet lands) * P(landed bullet is a headshot) =0.1, So in your calculation, it's $$(n \in {0,1,2}) : {7 \choose n} 0.5^{7-n} (0.5 \times 0.8)^n$$

Comment: I guess I was just hung up on the 0.5*0.8 part for the landed bullet not to be a headshot.

Comment: Yes your expression ${7 \choose n} 0.5^{7-n} (0.5 \times 0.8)^n, 0 \leq n \leq 2$ is a good representation.